# What is beam confinement?

Tags: vortex, non-linear-optics, solitons

In the context of the propagation of an electromagnetic wave and optical vortex solitons, I came across the term "beam confinement". Particularly, beam confinement requires the amplitude of the electromagnetic wave to decay exponentially fast at infinity. Is beam confinement a physically necessary property of an electromagnetic wave propagating trough some medium? Any references or discussions is highly appreciated.

Comment: It can mean confinement in spatial, angular (e.g., flash light vs. laser), temporal (e.g., short vs. long duration pulse), or frequency (e.g., narrow- vs. wide-band) depending on context.

Comment: My conclusion is that this is not a common term and should not be used loosely to describe localized optical vortex solitons.

Answer (score 0):

(Not totally sure this will answer your question) Any beam with a super-critical angle of incidence on an interface of two different indexes (from large to low index) is totally reflected and will have an exponential "evanescent" tail (few hundreds of nm for visible light). For example, in a fiber that's how the beam is "confined", and TIRF microscopy makes use of the tiny evanescent field. For those solitons where dispersion/diffraction is equilibrated by the non linearity of the medium, the latter produces an index profile similar to a fiber by Kerr effect (the local index is proportional to the local intensity). The beam "guides" itself and becomes a soliton.

I don't know if the tail of the soliton becomes necessarily exponentially-decaying, but maybe we can see the step-like index change of a fiber (which gives an exponential tail for the guided beam) as a limit case for a kerr soliton, where the index change is enough to guide, but not a steep step.